# iPhone / Three20: Adding a dynamic list of labels to a tablecell as a subview

Tags: iphone, ios, three20

I'm writing an iPhone app using the `Three20` framework and I'm struggling to figure out how I can add a dynamic list of `UILabel`s to a table cell.

I've attempted to subclass a `TTTableTextItem` and `TTTableTextItemCell` in order to display my dynamic list, but I'm having a hard time trying to write the `layoutSubviews`, `setObject` and `initWithStyle` methods.

I've read about subclassing [here](http://twocentstudios.com/blog/?p=25#comments) and [here](http://mattvague.com/three20-tttableitem-tutorial) and whilst I can replicate these simple examples where the table cells have a static number of controls, I've still not had much luck attempting to recreate something where the number of controls are dynamic based on the data that is passed to the table cell.

The data I'm pulling is a list of `Employee`s, and each employee has an `NSArray` of one or more `Job`s (so obviously the cell height needs to be dynamic, as does the list of labels that represent the jobs).

Each `Job` has a name, and a colour associated with it.

My intention is to create cells that look similar to the following:

---

Cell One

- "Employee One"
- "Job-1 colour label" "Job-1 Name Label"
- "Job-2 colour label" "Job-2 Name Label"
- ....
- "Job-n colour label" "Job-n Name"

---

Cell Two

- "Employee Two"
- "Job-1 colour label" "Job-1 Name Label"
- "Job-2 colour label" "Job-2 Name Label"
- ....
- "Job-n colour label" "Job-n Name"

---

If someone could help point me in the right direction, that'd be much appreciated!

Comment: Perhaps you should consider to change your design in a way, that you have one table cell for employee name followed by a variable number of table cells for the employee's jobs, followed by the next employee's name, and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell, there isn't an easy way to do what I'm after here.  @tonklon's suggestion of changing my design was the best option here and is exactly what I did.